# Relation between closed 1-chain and closed paths

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\gamma\in Z_1X=\mathrm{kernal}\,\partial_{1}$, i.e., a closed 1-chain. Prove there exists a 1-chain $\delta=\sum_in_i\delta_i$, where each $\delta_i$ is a closed path, such that $\gamma-\delta\in B_1X=\mathrm{image}\,\partial_2=$ constant 1-chains, i.e., $\gamma$ is homologous to $\delta$.

How do I prove this? Can we easily construct those closed paths $\delta_i$ from the components of $\gamma$?

Also, is there a generalization of this for each $n$-chains?

Comment: First, you are confusing cycles and boundaries. Second: Did you already learn Hurewicz theorem? If you do, then solving the problem will be easy, otherwise, you would have to rediscover a part if it's proof in the case of the 1st homology group.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a 1-chain, shouldn't it be in the image of $\partial_2$?

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: @studiosus For your first part, 1-cycle is closed 1-chain?

Comment: If you look into your textbook, you realize that $Z_k$ is the kernel of $\partial: C_k\to C_{k+1}$ and $B_k$ is the image of $\partial: C_{k-1}\to C_{k}$.

Comment: @studiosus Yes you are correct. Thanks!

Comment: @studiosus I am confused. When I learned homology, the boundary operator decreased dimension, so $\partial \colon C_k \to C_{k-1}$. What did change since then?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oops, I just put the arrows in the wrong direction (not for the first time!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the [Hurewicz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem), which includes the statement that for path-connected $X$ the natural map
$$
\pi_1(X,x)\to H_1(X)
$$ 
is surjective. This means that every 1-cycle in $X$ is homologous to a loop in $X$. If $X$ is not connected, apply this theorem to each path-connected component of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem:

First, write $\gamma=\sum_in_i\gamma_i$. We may assume all $n_i>0$ by reversing some of the $\gamma_i$. Next, we do induction on $n=\sum_in_i$. For $n=1$, the result is trivial. For $n>1$, $\gamma_1(1)=\gamma_k(0)$ for some $k$. If $k=1$, then $\gamma_1$ is already a closed path. Then the rest $\gamma-\gamma_1$ has less sum of all coefficients. By induction, it can be written as a sum of closed paths. If $k>1$, let $\delta=\gamma_1*\gamma_k$, which is homologous to $\gamma_1+\gamma_k$. Then $\gamma'=\delta+(n_1-1)\gamma_1+(n_k-1)\gamma_k+\sum_{i\neq1,k}n_i\gamma_i$, which is homologous to $\gamma$. Again, the sum of coefficients of $\gamma'$ is $(\sum_in_i)-1$. By induction, $\gamma'$ can be written as a sum of closed paths.